# How to solve $\int \dfrac{x^5\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Consider the integral

$$\int \dfrac{x^5\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

How to start integrating?
Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Integrate by part : $\ln$ as the first term

Comment: @ lab bhattacharjee we have $3$ terms how can we integrate by parts

Comment: @ArchisWelankar, what do you mean by 'term' here? We can take anything as $u$ and $dv$ when integrating by parts. For example, we can take $x^5dx$ (or $x^3dx$, or $xdx$) as $dv$ and the rest of the expression as $u$, or we can take $dx/ \sqrt{1-x^2}$ as $dv$ and the rest as $u$. Refresh the proof of integration by parts formula and the definition of a function

Comment: No got it now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\int \dfrac{x^5\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx 
$$
$$
u = \ln\frac{x+1}{1-x}  \quad dv = \frac{x^5 dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$
$$
v = \int \frac{x^5 dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \quad x = \sin\theta  \quad v = \int \sin^5\theta d\theta = -\int (1 - 2\cos^2\theta + \cos^4\theta ) d\cos\theta = \\ - \cos\theta + 2/3\cos^3\theta - 1/5\cos^5\theta = -\sqrt{1-x^2}+2/3(1-x^2)^{3/2} - 1/5 (1-x^2)^{5/2}
$$
$$
du = \frac{1-x}{1+x} \frac{2dx}{(1-x)^2} = du = \frac{2dx}{(1+x)(1-x)}
$$
$$
\int \dfrac{x^5\ln\left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = (\ln\frac{x+1}{1-x})(-\sqrt{1-x^2}+2/3(1-x^2)^{3/2} - 1/5 (1-x^2)^{5/2}) - \int [(-\sqrt{1-x^2}+2/3(1-x^2)^{3/2} - 1/5 (1-x^2)^{5/2})\frac{2dx}{(1+x)(1-x)}]
$$
$$
\int [(-\sqrt{1-x^2}+2/3(1-x^2)^{3/2} - 1/5 (1-x^2)^{5/2})\frac{2dx}{(1+x)(1-x)}] = \int [(-(1-x^2)^{-1/2}+2/3(1-x^2)^{1/2} - 1/5 (1-x^2)^{3/2})2dx] 
$$
$$
\int [(-(1-x^2)^{-1/2}dx = -\arcsin(x)
$$
$$
\int 2/3(1-x^2)^{1/2} dx = 2/3 [\frac{1}{2}\left(\arcsin \left(x\right)+\frac{1}{2}\sin \left(2\arcsin \left(x\right)\right)\right)]
$$
$$
\int 1/5 (1-x^2)^{3/2} dx = 1/5[x\left(1-x^2\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}+\frac{3}{8}\left(\arcsin \left(x\right)-\frac{1}{4}\sin \left(4\arcsin \left(x\right)\right)\right)]
$$

All the integrals involved have been evaluated. Now you need to sum :)

Comment: Starting with $x=\tanh(y)$ I got $$-\frac1{15}(16+8x^2+6x^4)\tanh^{-1}(x)\sqrt{1-x^2}-\frac1{60}(25+6x^2)x\sqrt{1-x^2}+\frac{89}{30}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac x{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)+C$$ Both solutions agree with the numerical solution, so they are the same to within a constant.

Comment: nice :) thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 4):

Using the substitution $ x = \sin(t) $
The integral simplifies to
$$\int \sin^5t \cdot \ln \left[\frac{1+ \sin(t)}{1-\sin(t)}\right] dt$$
Further simplifications yields:
$$ 2\int \sin^5t \cdot \ln[\sec(t)+\tan(t)] dt $$
we recognize $\ln[\sec(t)+\tan(t)]$ as the antiderivative of $\sec(t)$ which suggests integrating by parts with $u = \ln[\sec(t)+\tan(t)]$ and $dv = \sin^5t \cdot dt$.

Comment: This is a nice approach.  (I think you mean this is an antiderivative of $\sec t$.)